# sort a dictionary by value and key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
    'Horror': 2, 
    'Romance': 2, 
    'Comedy': 2, 
    'Action': 3, 
    'Adventure': 1, 
    'History': 2
}
```

I want to sort by values but when values is equal, I want to sort by alphabetic. that mean output is:

```
Action : 3
Comedy : 2
History : 2
Horror : 2
Romance : 2
Adventure : 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise the `key` argument within sorted to do use

#### Sorted

> `x[0] - Specifies your key`
>
> `x[1] - Specifies your values`

Essentially within the lambda implementation you are giving precedence to the `values (- implies desc)` over `keys`

```
>>> d = {'Horror': 2, 'Romance': 2, 'Comedy': 2, 'Action': 3, 'Adventure': 1, 'History': 2}

>>> dict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0])))
{'Action': 3, 'Comedy': 2, 'History': 2, 'Horror': 2, 'Romance': 2, 'Adventure': 1}
```

Comment: what meaning -x?

Comment: If `x` is 3 then `-x` is `-3`. So the highest numbers will be treated as the lowest numbers during the comparison. It's for reversing the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` parameter of `sorted`.

Build a custom tuple with the value first and the key next, invert the order of sorting of the value by using the negative value:

```
d = {'Horror': 2, 'Romance': 2, 'Comedy': 2,
     'Action': 3, 'Adventure': 1, 'History': 2}

{k:v for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))}
```

output:

```
{'Action': 3,
 'Comedy': 2,
 'History': 2,
 'Horror': 2,
 'Romance': 2,
 'Adventure': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

updating key value after sorted.

```
   mydict = {}
    
    for i,v in sorted(d.items()):
        mydict.update({i:v})
    
    print(mydict)
```